# sharing rundeck jobs between users

Tags: rundeck

We are trying to find cron-like job executor for our project and are evaluating rundeck. Does anyone know if it is possible to share set of jobs between users based on their permissions? For instance all developers should be able to manage each-other's jobs (stupid example, I know ;-) )

Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Rundeck can control which users are allowed to do what against any project.

- [Authentication docs](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/authenticating-users.html)
- [Authorization docs](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/access-control-policy.html)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, Rundeck isn't meant for being a job scheduler. Have you considered using Jenkins to schedule jobs you've created in Rundeck? If you're already using some sort of CI solution (and hopefully it's Jenkins) you could us it to control the time and nature of your Rundeck job execution. If you went this route, you could set the permissions to each scheduled job with the [matrix based security option](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup).